# Which math departments in the U.S. have people known for their contributions to Lie-admissible algebras?

Tags: mathematics

Which math departments in the U.S. have people known for their contributions to [Lie-admissible algebras](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie-admissible_algebra)?

(I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1127343/128568) on Math SE, but it was voted off-topic there. I hope it's not too specialized of a question here.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try searching for "Lie admissible algebra" on [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet) and the [arXiv](http://www.arXiv.org).  There are a few papers each year that mention this topic, but it doesn't seem to be a major research area in its own right.  If you are thinking about topics for graduate school, this seems to me to be way too specific to narrow down to before choosing an advisor.  (I assume you aren't already working in this research area yourself: if you did, you'd have more information about who else is.)

As for math departments in the U.S., two of the authors of references in the article you linked to (Benkart and Osborn) are emeritus professors at Wisconsin, and Myung used to be at Northern Iowa but has since died.  You could try looking up the authors of papers on the topic that excite you, but this won't give you a wide range of schools in the U.S., especially now that Benkart and Osborn have retired.  Instead, I agree with Chris C that you'd be better off considering a broader area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And, yes, I heard Myung died. _R.i.p._

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a highly specific area, so you might want to consider a little broader area (Lie algebras in general?) of study. In the process you can of course study these specific areas, but forcing yourself into a uncommon area of interest might make the job search later more challenging.

Though, this does not mean you have to go to a place that doesn't study Lie-admissible algebras. The best to find places that actively study the subject is to look up the most recent papers to see who the authors are and their associated university. This can give you a selection of universities where you'll find a potential adviser.